# Settings Activity- new Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

Hi Can anyone tell me how to make dialog fragment like in image below and how to pass result back to activity?
[image]

Comment: first try it yourself. there are enough tutoriols which descripes that use case.

Comment: Hey there tutorials in online easily ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder editalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

editalert.setTitle("messagetitle");
editalert.setMessage("here is the message");


final EditText input = new EditText(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
input.setLayoutParams(lp);
editalert.setView(input);

editalert.setPositiveButton("Send via email", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


    }
});


editalert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom dilaog with a editext and two buttons.

dilog.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="OK" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/anuluj"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ok"
    android:text="Anuluj" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity set the cusotm layout to your dialog

```
public void showpopup()  
{
final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
d.setTitle("my title");
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
Button ok = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.ok);
final EditText ed= (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s= ed.getText().toString();//get text form editext

    }

});
 Button anuluj = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.anuluj);

    anuluj.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            d.cancel();

        }

    });
    d.show();

   }
```